# Are there any PPAs or debs for Postler and Dexter?

Tags: 10.04, installation

Are there any PPAs or .deb files I can download in order to get the Elementary applications Postler and Dexter in Ubuntu 10.04?

I have tried the `postler-dev` PPA but it does not have builds for 10.04.

Comment: have you given ppa:postler-dev/ppa a shot?

Comment: Yes, and when I run `apt-get update` this is part of the output: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/postler-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found`

Comment: Hmmm...that is the only one I am aware of.  However, I will look around and let you know if I run across something.

Comment: How about ppa:postler-dev/devel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question and say No. I haven't been able to find any PPAs or compatible .deb files for Dexter or Postler on Lucid.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lallenlowe/dexter-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dexter
```

Something else I have run across at http://elementaryos.org/discover/:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementaryart/elementarydesktop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postler dexter
```

Not sure how will the elementary os stuff will work, as Jupiter is based on Ubuntu 10.10 and not 10.04.

Comment: Neither of those work either. Just `W: Failed to fetch` `404  Not Found` with different sources. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I wish I could have been of greater assistance.